# Why does creating an inline version of GridBagConstraints not work?

Tags: java, swing, inline-code

In attempting to make some Swing code more readable, I have made an `InlineGridBagConstraints` class which looks like this:

```
public class InlineGridBagConstraints extends GridBagConstraints {

public InlineGridBagConstraints gridx(int x) {
    gridx = x;
    return this;
}

public InlineGridBagConstraints gridy(int y) {
    gridy = y;
    return this;
}

public InlineGridBagConstraints gridheight(int h) {
    gridheight = h;
    return this;
}

public InlineGridBagConstraints gridwidth(int w) {
    gridwidth = w;
    return this;
}

    // .... and so on, for all fields.

}
```

The intention is to change this kind of code:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 3;
myJPanel.add(myJButton, c);

c.gridx = 3;
c.gridwidth = 2;
myJPanel.add(myOtherJButton, c);

c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 5;
c.gridheight = 4;
myJPanel.add(yetAnotherJButton, c);
```

...with something much easier to understand and read, like this:

```
InlineGridBagConstraints c = new InlineGridBagConstraints();
myJPanel.add(myJButton, c.gridx(2).gridy(1).gridwidth(3));
myJPanel.add(myOtherJButton, c.gridx(3).gridy(1).gridwidth(2);
myJPanel.add(yetAnotherJButton, c.gridx(1).gridy(5).gridheight(4);
```

However, the above code isn't working.  When I attempt it, all of the components occupy the same area in the center of the `JPanel` and overlap one another.  They are not spaced out in the `GridBagLayout`.  If I use the uglier version with the regular `GridBagConstraints`, however, it works perfectly as intended.

I have tried typecasting the `InlineGridBagConstraints` into `GridBagConstraints`, thinking that perhaps that was an issue (even though it shouldn't be), but that didn't help at all.

I've run out of ideas.  Does anyone know why this is occurring or what the key difference between the first (standard) and the second (inline) implementations is?

Comment: IMHO, what you're attempting to do is actually making your code less readable. But if you want to continue down this path, read up on the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: I understand that "readable" is subjective.  I do disagree with you, as using standard `GridBagConstraints` tends to make long, tedious code out of something that should be readable in a simple "statement", in my opinion.  Thanks for the link.  I'll check it out. :)

Comment: Using that layout manager always makes for long/tedious code ;]

Comment: If someone knows of a way I can put the extensive code in a box that the viewer has to click on in order to expand it (so that it looks a lot better for everyone) that would be great.

Comment: I have always used the same GridBagConstants object in all of my Swing projects with no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no idea what your `GUIConstants` defines, as we don't see it, but changing the reset() method in `InlineGridBagConstraints` to the one below, makes your UI look as you probably expected:

```
  public InlineGridBagConstraints reset() {
    gridx = 0;
    gridy = 0;
    gridheight = 1;
    gridwidth = 1;
    insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the same results as you.  When I use `GridBagConstraints` I do not get buttons overlapping.  (I do set some anchor and fill values.)  I've supplied code and screenshots above.

Comment: Laughably enough, those are my default values (even the Insets).  I will post my GUIConstants file shortly.

Comment: Don't post anything. The code, as I showed you works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can rely on what you wrote, this should work. So, I would suggest to start looking for other bugs in your code.

Are you setting the LayoutManager correctly in both examples?

**Update:** Try to get rid of the reset call in the constructor. The super class constructor will do the job correctly.

Comment: Yes, both versions were tried under the same LayoutManager settings (I literally replaced one implementation with the other in the same use/block of code).  However if you would like me to post more of the surrounding code, I'll do so.

Comment: I've added the surrounding code as well as screenshots of the results I get using both methods.

Comment: It may be the case that the super constructor will do the same thing, but removing `reset()` from the constructor didn't help. :)